# get meta element property with Javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How would i construct a Javascript regex to get the content attribute from the following meta element?

```
<meta content="59.949444" property="og:latitude">
```

This is what my code looks like so far:

```
var url = 'test.html';

$.get(url, function(data){

  var pattern = /property="og:latitude"\scontent=".+?"/;   
  var matches = data.match(pattern);

  console.info(matches[0]);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the order of the items:

```
/content=\"(.+)\"\s+property=\"og:latitude\"/
```

Comment: Works. I used pattern2 =/(?:[-]|\d)(\d+)\.(\d+)/ to get the actual coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//...
     var pattern = /property="og:latitude"\scontent="(.+?)"/;   
      var matches = data.match(pattern);
      console.info(matches[1]);
```